# How can I determine if a marker is currently being clustered in MarkerClusterer 2.0.15

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer, googlemapsjs-markerclusterer

I’ve been using MarkerClustererPlus for some time without issue.
But it uses now deprecated calls to addDomListener which now generate hundreds of warning messages which state “the feature will continue to work and there is no plan to decommission it”.

I’m tired of seeing the warning messages in my developer console.

It appears MarkerClustererPlus will be deprecated itself soon in favor of a new flavor of MarkerClusterer (currently 2.0.15).

So I have begun migrating my code.  For rendering efficiency and auto-zooming functionality, I need to know if a marker is currently in any cluster.  I’ve been doing this brute force by using the getClusters method available in MarkerClustererPlus and then repeated getMarkers calls for each cluster.

The plethora of methods in MarkerClustererPlus are not there in MarkerClusterer 2.0.15

Bottom line.  How can I determine if a marker is currently being clustered in MarkerClusterer 2.0.15.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up adding a method to the distribution index.min.js that looks like this:

```
{
    key: "isMarkerClustered",
    value: function(m) {
        var imcReturn = false;
        this.clusters.every(function(c) {
            if (c.markers.length > 1 ) {
                c.markers.every(function(d) {
                    if (d === m) {
                        imcReturn=true;
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                })
            }
            if (imcReturn) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        })
        return imcReturn;
    }
}
```

I can check by doing

```
 mc = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer ...
```

and then

```
 mc.isMarkerClustered(marker)
```